# how to convert coldfusion into php

Tags: php, coldfusion

This is my code and i want to convert it in php. pls. i need a help thanks.

Comment: This is an extremely borad question.  What part don't you understand?  Do you have a specific question?  We're happy to help, but we're not going to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure private code like this should be posted publicly?

It's great you took on a outsourcing contract that's over your head.

If you can't understand cfml I doubt you understand php to implement this basic XML example in it.

Sorry, just being honest, no one likes being misled.